# IF statement in ON clause

Tags: mysql, php

Can you help correct the syntax for this code?

```
INNER JOIN Users u 
ON case when c.sender = ? then c.reciever = u.id else c.sender = u.id
```

How do I do I put a `CASE` statement in a `JOIN` clause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to keep the comparison column outside of your `CASE` statement.

```
INNER JOIN Users u 
ON u.id = CASE WHEN c.sender = ? then c.reciever else c.sender END
```

Comment: You can also rewrite as `ON c.sender = ? AND u.id = c.reciever OR c.sender <> ? AND u.id = c.sender`

Comment: And I would never use it but in mysql boolean values work in CASE expressions. They were only missing the `END` and it would work ok (although not so efficiently): `ON case when c.sender = 1 then c.receiver = u.id else c.sender = u.id END`

Comment: @ypercube's first suggestion would probably be easier for the optimizer to use to come up with the best query plan (although I would say add parentheses to clarify the operator precedence).  With no context, it's hard to say, but using `CASE` inside `ON` (or `WHERE`, just like using any functions with column values as arguments) could constrain the number of plans the optimizer may be able to  consider, limit its flexibility to re-order the tables in inner joins, and could increase the possibility of full table scans.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Feel free to do a `CASE` study (geddit? ;-)) I'd be interested in seeing what the results were!